# Grails call function without redirect

Tags: grails, redirect

In my gsp page, after clicking on an image, i want to save something to the database but don't want to leave that page / redirect. Is that possible using Grails?

Using this:

```
<g:link action="addF" params="[prog: it3.id]" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'Are you sure you want to add this as favourite ?')}');">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="${resource(dir:"images", file: "f.png") }" width="21" height="18"/>
                                </g:link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<g:remoteLink 
    action="addF"
    params="[prog: it3.id]"
    before="if (!confirm('${message(code: 'Are you sure you want to add this as favourite ?')}')) return false;"
    onComplete="alert('Marked as favorite')">
      <img src="${resource(dir:'images', file: 'f.png') }" width="21" height="18"/>
</g:remoteLink>
```

For this AJAX functionality you require jQuery plugin:

```
grails install-plugin jquery
```

If you have no javascript library installed, the `remoteLink` will fall back to a normal link. You will need to include the library into your html-`<head>`: `<g:javascript library="jquery" />`

Comment: hey. thanks for the fast answer. I tried your approach, and the page is indeed refreshing. Is it intented to? And the onComplete is also not showing up

Comment: do you have jquery plugin installed?

Comment: Do not forget to include the library, see answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Ajax? http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html